# Removing elements of a specific length from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list such as this:

```
    {{{-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, _, _, _, _}, {-1, 0, -1, 2,  1, _, _, _, _}, {4}, {-1, 1, 0, 1, 1, _, _, _, _}}, {{0, -1, 0, 1, 1, _, _, _, _}, {0, -1, -1, 2, 1, _, _, _, _}, {1, -1, 0, 1,  1, _, _, _, _}, {4}}, {{4}, {0, 0, -1, 2, 1, _, _, _, _}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, _, _, _, _}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, _, _, _, _}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, {{4}, {0, 0, 0, 2, 1, _, _, _, _}, {-1, 0, 0, 2, 1, _, _, _, _}, {0, -1, 0, 2, 1, _, _, _, _}}}
```

I want to remove the elements that have length=9 such as {-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, _, _, _, _} leaving the elements that have length=1 such as {4}. I have tried many approaches using delete cases but with no success.

Comment: newList=Select[listOfLists,Length[#]!=9&]

Comment: Just to clarify: what is your desired outcome? `Cases[list, Except[ConstantArray[_, 9]], {2}]` giving  {{4}, {4}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, {4}} or `list /. ConstantArray[_, 9] -> Nothing`  giving  {{{4}}, {{4}}, {{4}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, {{4}}} ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[#, x_ /; Length[x] == 9] & /@ yourList
```

Comment: Might be more natural with a [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) statement: `Select[#,GreaterThan[9]@*Length]`. (Note that this uses [`GreaterThan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GreaterThan.html) which was introduced in 10.3).

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
Pick[list, Unitize[Map[Length, list, {2}] - 9], 1]
```

If speed is an issue, `Pick` is around twice as fast on large lists as `DeleteCases` or `Select`:

```
data2 = Join @@ Table[data, {1000}];
Pick[data2, Unitize[Map[Length, data2, {2}] - 9], 1] // Flatten // Length // RepeatedTiming
DeleteCases[#, x_ /; Length[x] == 9] & /@ data2 // Flatten // Length // RepeatedTiming
Select[#, LessThan[9]@*Length] & /@ data2 // Flatten // Length // RepeatedTiming
Select[#, Length[#] != 9 &] & /@ data2 // Flatten // Length // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.010, 12000}  Pick
  {0.020, 12000}  DeleteCases
  {0.021, 12000}  Select, assuming no sublists longer than 9
  {0.018, 12000}  Select, general case
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it using recursion:

```
deleteRecursively[{}] = {};
deleteRecursively[{x_Integer}] := {x};
deleteRecursively[x : {_List ..}] := With[{crit = 9},
  If[Length@First[x] == crit, Join[{Null}, deleteRecursively[Rest@x]],
  Join[{First@x}, deleteRecursively[Rest@x]]
 ]
]

result = Map[deleteRecursively]@list

(* {{Null, Null, {4}, Null}, {Null, Null, Null, {4}}, {{4}, Null, Null, Null},
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, {{4}, Null, Null, Null}} *)
```

You can remove `Null` (which i have used to preserve the structure of your list) using `DeleteCases[result, Null, {2}]`

```
(* {{{4}}, {{4}}, {{4}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, {{4}}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slot-free version using the newish operator forms (I like slot-free operator forms):

```
Select[UnequalTo[9] @* Length] /@ list
```

> {{{4}}, {{4}}, {{4}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 2}}, {{4}}}

Comment: cool use of UnequalTo !